# Starting with an empty SwiftUI @FetchRequest

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I'm using `@FetchRequest` to get a big list (+7k) of entities and I'd like to initiate the view with an empty result set which will be filled later with `searchable()`

I tried using a predicate I know will return an empty set but it seems hacky, isn't there a more standard way to do that?

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
    SortDescriptor(\.infinitive)
], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "infinitive CONTAINS %@", "feofpezk")) var verbs: FetchedResults<Verb>
```

I saw that I can also try something like this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "FALSEPREDICATE")
```

Which seems just a bit less hacky but still.

Comment: The problem you'll face is if you use the change of the searchable string to update the predicate, it'll be lost when the view is re-init by the parent view and it'll be back to your false predicate. You can try setting the predicate at the top of body (it's not a state mutation).

Comment: Yes that's what I'm doing, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSPredicate(value:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1417329-init) with `false` to say "no values"

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [
    SortDescriptor(\.infinitive)
], predicate: NSPredicate(value: false)) var verbs: FetchedResults<Verb>
```

Comment: Simple enough, thank you!